# excel won't close after procedure is run

Tags: excel, vba

I run this code and excel session won't destroy or close.  I know that I am not using sheets.add or ws.delete because it says With Validation and I don't know how to use the single lines declaring my objects.  I don't know the syntax I guess.  Here is the code.  Can someone point out how to fix it?

```
Public Function ComboLists()
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim MyFileName As String
Dim bfile As String
Dim MyList(1) As String
Dim lRow As Long

bfile = "S:\_Reports\KSMS\Designated Letter\KSMS Designated Letter - "

MyFileName = bfile & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".xls"

On Error Resume Next
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(MyFileName)
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
ws.Activate
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

MyList(0) = "Approve Location"
MyList(1) = "Delete Location"

lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

i = 2

For Each c In wb.Sheets(1).Range("M" & lRow)

If ws.Cells(i, 12).Value = "US" Then
rng = "M" & i '& ":" & "Z" & i

With Range(rng).Validation
.Delete
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
     Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(MyList, ",")
wb.CheckCompatibility = False
wb.Save
wb.CheckCompatibility = True
End With
Else
rng = "A" & i & ":" & "L" & i
With xlApp.Range(rng).Validation
ws.Delete
wb.CheckCompatibility = False
wb.Save
wb.CheckCompatibility = True
'wb.Close savechanges:=False
End With
End If


i = i + 1

Next c

Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
ws.Activate

ws.Cells.Rows("1:1").Select

wb.CheckCompatibility = False
wb.Save
wb.CheckCompatibility = True
wb.Close savechanges:=False

xlApp.Quit
xlApp.Quit
xlApp.Quit
xlApp.Quit

Set xlApp = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing

Exit Function

End Function
```

I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Where is this code running? If it is running in Excel then you shouldn't need the variable `xlApp` at all.

Comment: I believe the issue lies in that the workbook running the code is closed, so the macro ceased to operate beyond the line `wb.Close`

Comment: It opens a workbook and is adding drop downs validatioin to the cells in a loop.

Comment: I fixed it with the following code:

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

to

```
lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

or else you will still have a reference to the Excel application after your code finishes.

With the unqualified `Rows`, your application (Word? Access? PowerPoint?) needs to create a dummy `ActiveSheet` object to be used by the method.  Until that dummy object is destroyed, an instance of Excel needs to be maintained.  That object won't get destroyed until you exit your application and therefore the instance of Excel will hang around until you exit your app.

---

I didn't spot it originally, but you also have an unqualified `Range`

```
With Range(rng).Validation
```

will need to be

```
With ws.Range(rng).Validation
```

---

The golden rule of using multiple Application objects is **always fully qualify everything**.

Answer (score -1):

```
Public Function ComboLists()
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim MyFileName As String
Dim bfile As String
Dim MyList(1) As String
Dim lRow As Long

bfile = "S:\_Reports\KSMS\Designated Letter\KSMS Designated Letter - "

MyFileName = bfile & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".xls"

On Error Resume Next
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(MyFileName)
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
ws.Activate
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

MyList(0) = "Approve Location"
MyList(1) = "Delete Location"

lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

MsgBox lRow

i = 2

'For Each c In wb.Sheets(1).Range("M2:M1000") '" & Range("V" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row)
For Each c In wb.Sheets(1).Range("M" & lRow)

If ws.Cells(i, 12).Value = "US" Then
rng = "M" & i '& ":" & "Z" & i

With xlApp.Range(rng).Validation
.Delete
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
     Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(MyList, ",")
wb.CheckCompatibility = False
wb.Save
wb.CheckCompatibility = True
DoEvents
End With
Else
rng = "A" & i & ":" & "L" & i
With xlApp.Range(rng).Validation
ws.Delete
wb.CheckCompatibility = False
wb.Save
wb.CheckCompatibility = True
DoEvents
End With
DoEvents
End If

i = i + 1

Next c

DoEvents

Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
ws.Activate

ws.Cells.Rows("1:1").Select

wb.CheckCompatibility = False
wb.Save
wb.CheckCompatibility = True
wb.Close savechanges:=False
DoEvents
MsgBox "quit"
xlApp.Quit

Set xlApp = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing

Exit Function

End Function
```

I add the lrow lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row I added ws. in front of cells and ws in front of rows and that helped destroy the session

Comment: It is a good idea to qualify your `Range` objects correctly too - `xlApp.Range` is equivalent to `xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range`.  It would be better to use `ws.Range` which specifies exactly which sheet in which workbook in which instance of Excel that you are referring to.